# innerHTML population through Javascript is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I have a HTML form in which there is a  +  tag. I would like to sort the list of options through Javascript. I wrote a code which works in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but doesn't work in Internet Explorer. I am pasting the Javasript code below. Is something missing in my code?

```
window.onload = function () {
categoryOptions = $('category').innerHTML;
$('category').innerHTML = sortCategoryOptions(categoryOptions);
};
```

Function definition for sortCategoryOptions() is given below:

```
function sortCategoryOptions(categoryOptions) {
var eachOption = categoryOptions.split('</option>');
for (var i = 0; i < (eachOption.length - 1); i++) {
    eachOption[i] = eachOption[i] + '</option>';
}
eachOption.sort();
optionsSorted = '';
for (var i = 0; i < eachOption.length; i++) {
    optionsSorted = optionsSorted + eachOption[i];
}
return optionsSorted; 
}
```

categoryOptions field has following content

```
<option>Option3</option>
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option4</option>
```

Expected output

Comment: why are you mixing and matching jquery objects with dom elements?

Comment: @DanielA.White: I don't think that's jQuery. It looks like `$` is just an alias for `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>For starters, you are literally looking for a `<category>` tag, which I'm fairly sure was not your intent.</del> Disregard, as pointed out in comments it looks like `$` is an alias of `document.getElementById` here, not `jQuery`.

Aside from that, using `innerHTML` to sort is a *horrible* idea, even more so because you're relying on `</option>` to not be changed by the browser's parser (which it invariably will, to `</OPTION>`)

So, with that in mind, and the assumption that you are working on `<select id="category">`, give this a try:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('category'),
        arr = [].concat.apply([],sel.children), // convert NodeList to array
        l = arr.length, i;
    arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1});
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) sel.appendChild(arr[i]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Yes, I am using $ as short cut for document.getElementById()

Comment: In future, it's probably a good idea to tell people that up front ;) 99.99% of the time you see `$` it's there for jQuery.

Comment: By the way, is above solution jQuery or Javascript. I am getting error when above script is executed in IE6-8 and I was trying to get rid of the error but wasn't able to so far...

Comment: JScript object expected. Its happening in line "arr = [].concat.apply([],sel.children), "

Comment: That's strange, there should be no syntax error there. Try `Array.prototype.concat.apply([],sel.children)`, and if that still doesn't work I'll give you a NodeList to array helper function.

Comment: Okay, here: `arr = (function(c) {var o = [], l = c.length, i; for(i=0; i<l; i++) o[i] = c[i]; return o;})(sel.children)`